# How to write a character update regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

How to write a regular expression which can handle the following substitution scenario.

```
Hello, this is a ne-
w line of text wher-
e we are trying hyp-
henation.
```

i have a short Python code which handles breaking long one_line strings into a multi_line string and produces output similar to the code sample given above

I want a regular expression that takes care of the single hyphenated character like in first and second line and just pulls up the single hyphenated character on the previous like.

something like `re.sub("-\n<any character>","<the any character>\n")`

I can not find a way on how to handle the hyphenated character

below is some further information about the question

```
Word = "Python string comparison is performed using the characters in both strings. The characters in both strings are compared one by one."

def hyphenate(word, x):
    for i in range(x, len(word), x):
        word = word[:i] + ("\n" if (word[i] == " " or word[i-1] == " " ) else "-\n") + (word[i:] if word[i] != " " else word[(i+1):])
    return(word)

print(hyphenate(Word, 20))
```

#Produced output

```
Python string compar-
ison is performed 
using the character-  <=
s in both strings.
The characters in b- <=
oth strings are co-
mpared one by one.
```

#Desired output

```
Python string compar-
ison is performed 
using the characters  <=
 in both strings.
The characters in  <=
both strings are co- 
mpared one by one.
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code in your question. Could you please do share sample of expected output in your question for better understanding of your question.

Comment: please have a look at the question now.

Comment: It's not clear why your desired output still includes some hyphenated words. What is the principle for which hyphens to remove?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the trailing character at all.

```py
re.sub(r'-\n', '')
```

If for some reason you do need to capture the character, you can use `r'\1'` to refer back to it.

```py
re.sub(r'-\n([aeiou])', r'\1')
```

The notation `r'...'` produces a "raw string" where backslashes only represent themselves. In Python, backslashes in strings are otherwise processed as escapes - for example, `'\n'` represents the single wharacter newline, whereas `r'\n'` represents the two literal characters backslash and `n` (which in a regex *match* a literal newline).